# How is it possible for reponse.json() to return a string?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

Here is the code I use:

```
fetch('url.php', {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    body: "urls=" + encodeURIComponent(
        JSON.stringify(data)
    )
}).then(function(response) {
    response.json().then(function(response_as_json) {
        console.log(typeof response_as_json === 'string'); // returns true
    })
})
```

The questions are:

1. Why is `response.json()` returning a string?
2. Since the data is a string, why doesn't the browser throw an error?

I cannot provider the data which is returned. It is too much data and I can't really parse it before posting here. But, after all, you should understand my problem.

The JSON can be a string and not only an object as I taught.

I am quite confused now, while JSON means *"JavaScript **Object** Notation"*.

Comment: Have you read [the MDN page for `json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json#return_value)...? "**Return value**: A Promise that resolves to a JavaScript object. This object could be anything that can be represented by JSON — an object, an array, a string, a number…" Unless you can provide a [mre] we cannot affirmatively say why `response.json()` returns a `string` in your specific case.

Comment: Note that ```headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    body: "urls=" + encodeURIComponent(
        JSON.stringify(data)
    )``` is more simply written as `body: new URLSearchParams({urls: JSON.stringify(data)})`

Comment: @esqew Well, i read the MDN page, but I thought I didn't understand correctly. To be honest, I thought a json can be only an object....

Comment: _" I thought a json can be only an object...."_ That's wrong. "A JSON" is a string in JSON format. JSON values are numbers, null, objects and arrays. The root element is a JSON value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top level value in a JSON text can be any kind of JSON value, including strings.

```js
{
  const jsonText = `"valid JSON"`;
  const parsedValue = JSON.parse(jsonText);
  console.log([parsedValue, typeof parsedValue]);
}

{
  const jsonText = `["valid JSON"]`;
  const parsedValue = JSON.parse(jsonText);
  console.log([parsedValue, typeof parsedValue]);
}
```

---

This wasn't always the case. In the original JSON spec the top level value had to be an object or array. Some parsers that have not been updated may still error.

---

From the information you've provided there is no way to tell why the API you are using has been designed to return a string expressed as JSON.

The browser doesn't error because no error has been made.

Comment: I thought a json can only be an object, nothing else. I'm very confused now...

Comment: Did you log them in arrays to further confuse the situation?

Comment: @pilchard — No. To associate the values with each other in the Stackoverflow implementation of console.log.